# OSGi Component's default configuration value contains escaped backslash

Tags: java, osgi, aem

Below is a code of my simple OSGi component

```
@Component(metatype = true, label = "My Component", policy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
@Property(label = "My Component's expression", name = "my.expression", value = "/5 * * * * ? *")
public class MyComponent {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyComponent.class);

    @Reference
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Activate
    public void activate(final ComponentContext context) {
        final String quartzExpression = PropertiesUtil.toString(
                context.getProperties().get("my.expression"), "");
        ScheduleOptions options = scheduler.EXPR(quartzExpression).name("MyJob");
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                log.info("Hello World!");

            }
        }, options);
    }
}
```

What it is supposed to do: it takes a configuration value that is a Quartz expression and uses it to schedule a job that logs a simple greeting.

By default, I want the job to be executed every 5 seconds, which the default value of the property states. Now, since I also specify the `ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE`, I actually need to create the config. To do that, I go to the OSGi console's config manager, find `My Component` on the list and click it. At this moment, a request is sent to fetch the config dialog data. The response contains stuff like labels, names and, also, default value. In my case, the default value is returned as `/5\\ *\\ *\\ *\\ *\\ ?\\ *`, and is displayed on the dialog as `/5\ *\ *\ *\ *\ ?\ *`.

Now, if I manually remove all the backslashes, the configuration is saved, is later extracted properly and makes the component work as expected. My question is, why is the default value specified in the code not the same as what I receive from OSGi in the config manager?

Edit: after further investigation, I think it might be caused by Maven SCR Plugin that I use to generate component descriptors. It generates those two files: `.\target\classes\OSGI-INF\MyComponent.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><components xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0">
    <scr:component name="MyComponent" configuration-policy="require" activate="activate">
        <implementation class="MyComponent"/>
        <property name="my.expression" value="/5 * * * * ? *"/>
        <property name="service.pid" value="MyComponent"/>
        <reference name="scheduler" interface="org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.Scheduler" cardinality="1..1" policy="static" bind="bindScheduler" unbind="unbindScheduler"/>
    </scr:component>
</components>
```

And this one: `.\target\classes\OSGI-INF\metatype\MyComponent.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><metatype:MetaData xmlns:metatype="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/metatype/v1.0.0" localization="OSGI-INF/metatype/MyComponent">
    <OCD id="MyComponent" name="%MyComponent.name" description="%MyComponent">
        <AD id="my.expression" type="String" name="%MyComponent.my.expression" />
    </OCD>
    <Designate pid="MyComponent">
        <Object ocdref="MyComponent"/>
    </Designate>
</metatype:MetaData>
```

It looks like the `metatype` metadata is not generated properly.

Comment: Sling provides an OOTB mechanism for scheduling jobs. Is there a reason why you aren't using that? [Scheduling Jobs Using Sling](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/scheduling_jobs_usingsling/)

Comment: Yes, there is. This is a shortened version of my code, but in general I need to create multiple very similar jobs based on the configuration provided.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually an expected behavior of the Maven SCR Plugin that was implemented over two years ago to solve [problem with encoding regular expressions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-3542) as the default values - commit can be found [here](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/changelog/felix?cs=1470946).

Found it.

Comment: Nice find! This is the reason but what's the workaround you used?

Comment: I raised a bug on Felix's JIRA, and meanwhile decided to add the default configuration to the description of a property. Since the component has a mandatory policy that is not provided automatically, it has to be manually input anyway (for now at least).

Comment: @CptBartender, it seems the second link is not working. I need a solution for this problem too. When adding links, it is good to put the link with a description of it so the one who needs answer can at least search and try to find the link. Could you please update the link? Very much in need of the solution.